# Vue Slot rendering name instead of content

Tags: vue.js

When I use one of the vue select components I've tried, something strange happens. Where the list values were supposed to appear instead I'm getting the slot names. This will be much clearer in the example.

I've tried using **vue-multiselect, vue-select, & vue-cool-select** and I've come to the conclusion that this is not a library problem, but vue's  or maybe my configuration.

This example shows vue-multiselect but **happens with every library I've used so far**. It is the most basic example provided by the vue-multiselect documentation itself.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <multiselect
            v-model="value"
            :options="options"
            :searchable="false"
            :close-on-select="false"
            :show-labels="false"
            placeholder="Pick a value"
        ></multiselect>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                value: null,
                options: ['Select option', 'options', 'selected', 'mulitple']
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

This is what I get:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsVS3.png

Anyone got any idea why this might be happening?

Thank you!

Comment: That image was using vue-multiselect?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be working fine with this [code here.](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-iucbu)

```
<template>
  <div>
        <multiselect
            v-model="value"
            :options="options"
            :searchable="false"
            :close-on-select="false"
            :show-labels="false"
            placeholder="Pick a value"
        ></multiselect>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Multiselect from "vue-multiselect";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Multiselect
  },
  data() {
      return {
          value: null,
          options: ['Select option', 'options', 'selected', 'mulitple']
      }
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: I've tried adding the same dependencies as in your example but it still doesn't work. I think is something related with the vue slots being overridden by something else. But can't figure out what that could be. Got any idea?

Comment: Can I see you `package.json`?

Comment: Already posted the answer. It was completely my fault. Thanks for the help anyways.

Answer (score 0):

So I have a function in my project to handle translations called `_t()` which is also defined as a `Vue.prototype._t()`. And so it happens that Vue.prototype._t refers to the `renderSlot()` function.

Remember to never prototype Vue with a function called `_t()`. I lost nearly 4h until I tried commenting almost every line of code.